# Translate "avant la lettre" and “à force de servir”

Tags: traduction

- Auteur: Godard, Henri
- Titre: "Céline et cie"
- Editions Gallimard 2020

---

Referring to the work of novelists from de Balzac to Tolstoy, Godard writes:

> “Ceux-ci s’étaient proposé avant tout de susciter chez le lecteur une illusion de 
>   « vie » des personnages et d’un déroulement de leur histoire dans une sorte de présent. Ils avaient usé pour cela d’un mélange de psychologie et de sociologie **avant la lettre** : connaissance du « cœur humain », connaissance de secteurs particuliers de la société. Mais, **à force de servir**, le modèle avait révélé ses limites.” p10

Two translation questions:

1. **“avant la lettre”**: How to specify the actual meaning here of the literal “before the   letter”? What is the sense here?
2. **“à force de servir”**: DeepL translates this sentence as, “But, **by dint of serving**, the model had revealed its limitations.”
   The expression “by dint of” seems arcane since “dint” is used only in this one English expression and nowhere else. Is there a better way to translate **“à force de servir”** here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about translation to English, not about understanding the French or about translation _to_ French

Comment: "Avant la lettre" is a term of art used in printmaking.  It refers to the prints made before any lettering (author's name, caption …) has been added to them.  It's used figuratively in your example; it means that Tolstoy and Balzac were ahead of their time and were into sociology and psychology before there was even a name for it.

Comment: @grandtout “Avant la lettre” is also common enough in English, as in describing a Platonic dialogue as containing “gay pride avant la lettre,” to use one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"***Avant la lettre***" means a knowledge used or shown before the corresponding science has given its definition.

The second sentence, using "à force de servir" could be translated this way:

> "But the model had been used so often that in the end it came to show
>   its limits"